WebGL Cannot draw gl.POINTS and gl.LINE_STRIP at the same time
I am currently learning WebGL and for that i am creating an app that draws B-Spline curves. In my code i have option of drawing both the vertices and the lines connecting those vertices in my curve.
Its working well in my main desktop but once i switch to my laptop i lose the ability to display both at the same time. I either show the lines or the points;
        const numPoints = (curve.points.length - 3) * numSegments + 1;
        if (showPoints) {
            gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, numPoints);
        }
        if (showLines) {
            gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_STRIP, 0, numPoints);
        }

Some info about my machine;
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Vega 6 Graphics (radeonsi, raven, LLVM 18.1.8, DRM 3.58, 6.11.1-arch1-1)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 24.2.3-arch1.1
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.2.3-arch1.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 24.2.3-arch1.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

and my gpu:
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c3)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 85de
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
--
04:00.7 Non-VGA unclassified device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Sensor Fusion Hub
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 85de
    Kernel driver in use: pcie_mp2_amd

I tried switching gpu drivers. Nothing
